# css) I want to place Footer under the section, but it goes under the aside, beside article

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
   <header></header>
   <section>
       <nav>
       <aside>
       <article>
   </section>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

This is my HTML code's outline.
Whole code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/o3omng/466Gv/

```
/* semantics */
body { width : 1000px ; /* body 가로폭 1000px */
       margin : 0 auto ; /* body 가운데 정렬  */
       font-family : 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif ; /* 폰트 나눔고딕 */ }
header, section, nav, footer { display : block ; /*블럭 요소 지정 */ }
aside, article { display : inline-block ; /*인라인-블럭 요소 지정 */ }
```

and this is a part of my css code.
becasue of this css code, The semantic tags must placed like this :

header
nav
aside article
footer

but If i run my code, footer tag goes under the aside, beside the article.
like this :

header
nav 
aside article
footer extend of article

You can see it in Jsfiddle.
I want to place footer under the whole section.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you applied a float to the aside and article which are already inline-blocks.
because of that the section that wraps them didn't clear the content.

if you take the floats away and adjust the article with it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/466Gv/7/  (look at the end of the css tab)

```
/*  STACK OVERFLOW CHANGES */
.f_left, .f_right{
    float:none; /* because we already have inline-block*/
}
aside, article{
    vertical-align: top; /* to have them aligned nicely*/   
}
article{
    width: 800px; /* fit size, so it doesnt break into the next line */
}
nav{
    margin-bottom: 2em;  /* some breathing room for then nagivation */
}
```

hope this helped.

ps: you dont need to include the html and head tag in the fiddle. only the markup in the body is enough

Comment: Thank you! I was so busy that i copy and paste all the code of my HTML include Head.